# Overlay click tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to overlay a div over say a block of links, and let them click on the links, but using jQuery `.click()` or something to track the click?

Ex:

```
<div id="overlay"></div>

<a href="">Link</a> 
<a href="">Link</a> 
<a href="">Link</a> 
<a href="">Link</a>
```

I attempted something like:

```
#overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 220px;
        right: 0;
        width: 300px;
        height: 280px;
        background: #000;
        z-index: 50;
        color: #fff;
        opacity: 0.8;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

$(function() {
    $( "#overlay" ).click(function() {
       alert( "Clicked" );
    });
});
```

This lets me click through the div, but doesn't call the handler.  And IE isn't supporting pointer-events.

Now I know I can add tracking to the links, etc.. But I want to overlay this over an image, over flash ads, etc..

Any possible options? Basically want the jquery click handler to run and the link to still open.

Comment: can you not add a click function to the `div` that houses each ad?

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a solution that works with the overlay. It relies on getting the coordinates from the `click` event. It works in IE9 and Chrome, didn't test any other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need a div overlay, just attach to the anchor's click handler. Or, if you really want to use an overlay, you simply get the coordinates from the click event, and then find the element at those coordinates. There are various ways to do this, but the easiest is to temporarily hide the overlay, find the element at the click coordinates using `document.elementFromPoint()` (in supported browsers), and then re-show the overlay element. Then fire `click()` on the element you found at the click coordinates (if any).

JSFiddle demo (using overlay, tested in Chrome and IE9): http://jsfiddle.net/RMkV8/4/

Markup:

```
<a id='link1' href="http://stackoverflow.com" target=_blank>Link 1</a> 
<a id='link2' href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Link 2</a> 
<a id='link3' href="javascript:;">Link 3</a> 
<a id='link4' href="javascript:;">Link 4</a> 
<ul id='output'></ul>
<div id='overlay'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var clickHistory = [];

$("#overlay").click(function(event)
                    {
                        var x = event.pageX || event.clientX;
                        var y = event.pageY || event.clientY;
                        $("#overlay").hide();
                        var clickedElem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
                        $("#overlay").show();
                        $("#output").append("<li>Position: " + x + "," + y + "; Id: " + clickedElem.id + "; URL: " + clickedElem.href + "</li>");

                        clickHistory[clickHistory.length] = {Id: clickedElem.id, Url: clickedElem.href };

                        clickedElem.click();                        
                    });

// could push clickHistory to server via AJAX for tracking if desired...
```

JSFiddle demo (not using overlay): http://jsfiddle.net/RMkV8/1/

Markup:

```
<a id='link1' href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target=_blank>Link 1</a> 
<a id='link2' href="http://google.com/" target=_blank>Link 2</a> 
<a id='link3' href="javascript:;">Link 3</a> 
<a id='link4' href="javascript:;">Link 4</a> 
<ul id='output'></ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var clickHistory = [];

$("a").click(function()
             {            
                 clickHistory[clickHistory.length] = {Id: this.id, Url: this.href };
                 $("#output").append("<li>ID: " + this.id + ", URL: " + this.href + "</li>");
             });

// could push clickHistory to server via AJAX for tracking if desired...
```

Comment: I might be able to use this method, but I dont think they are all href, i believe some are flash ads also.. i will check .

Comment: Not sure how it will work with flash, but this method could be adapted to support other click targets than just `a`

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to have an overlay and allow to click on an element below.

You have to look for another solution. You could think about attaching events to all links, that allow you to track the clicks.

Comment: Not impossible; you could capture the coordinates from the `click` event and then find a hyperlink element at those coordinates, for example, then fire its `click` event or manually navigate to its `href` property.